# say-command mac speech synthesis, how to output sound on different channels?

Tags: python, macos, audio, terminal, speech

i'm trying to use `say`, macos speech synthesis program, and i'm failing to output the sound on the channel i desire (e.g. left or right).

`say` has a `--channels` tag, i tried to use some integers but it had no influences, also there is no specification in the man.

i checked `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` if my device has 2 output channels and it is the case.

i could not find any usable doc on `say` for that particular problem. I thought maybe it is possible to pipe the sound into another prog, but not tried yet. Also, it may be possible to just turn on/ off the volume of the channel I need/ don't need each time before i call say, but didn't look up yet how that would work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The channels option of the `say` command is sadly for controlling the number of output channels (mono, stereo, &c...) not the channel number. To achieve what you want I would look into Sound Flower which you can select as the out put device with the `-a` option. Then have a look at routing this to your specifications https://music.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-routing-audio-between-applications-using-soundflower--audio-16199

Comment: or Rogue Ameoba's Loopback may be the better candidate https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/